# how to calculate the mean of an array using grouping variables in python?

Tags: python, grouping, mean

I would like to calculate the mean of an array in python, using different grouping variables. For instance, I want to calculate the mean of all values in `column1`, for which `column2 == 2` and `column3 == a + 3`.

I've tried a for-loop & if-loop, but it seems extremely complicated and for the dimensions of my data way too confusing. Is there another way to group the data for certain conditions and calculate the mean for each combination of conditions individually?

I am looking for a function like `group_by()`, `summarise()` or `aggregate()` in R, just for python.

This is the loop I tried so far:

```
    for j in range(0,len(e_data)): #iterate for each row in e_data
      if e_data[j,6] == 0.0082:
        if e_data[j,1] == ped1:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped1+0.0082)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
        elif e_data[j,1] == ped2:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped2+0.0082)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
        elif e_data[j,1] == ped3:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped3+0.0082)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))]))
      if e_data[j,6] == 0.001:
        if e_data[j,1] == ped1:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped1+0.001)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
        elif e_data[j,1] == ped2:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped2+0.001)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
        elif e_data[j,1] == ped3:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped3+0.001)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
      if e_data[j,6] == 0.0235:
        if e_data[j,1] == ped1:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped1+0.0235)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
        elif e_data[j,1] == ped2:
          e_data[j,7] = mean(e_data[:,4][np.where((e_data[:,0] == (ped2+0.0235)) & (e_data[:,5] == i))])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to checkout [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), which does exactly what you need.

In the python world, Pandas is the definitive solution for data analysis tasks like what you have described.

Once you import your data (ideally in .csv format) into pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filepath_to_your_data')

## I want to calculate the mean of all values in column1, for which column2 == 2 and column3 == a + 3
df[(df.column2==2) & (df.column3 == a+3)].loc[:, 'column1'].mean()
```

Pandas also offers `groupby`, `describe` and `agg`

Comment: Okay thank you, that already helps a lot. So now in column2, I have 5 possible values and in column 3 I have 6 possible values and I want to have the mean for all these value combinations, so 30 mean values in total for each group (I have 10 groups). Do I have to write the same code line then 300 times or is there another way to group and shorten it up?

Comment: Pandas has a `groupby` function, all you have to do is to perform df.groupby(['column2', 'column3')['column1'].mean(), check out the examle here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm  If this is helpful, consider accept this answer